# Django Queryset filtering against list of strings

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to combine the django queryset filters `__in` and `__icontains`.

Ex: given a list of strings `['abc', 'def']`, can I check if an object contains anything in that list.

`Model.objects.filter(field__icontains=value)` combined with `Model.objects.filter(field__in=value)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Q expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q)

```
from django.db.models import Q

vals = ['abc', 'def']  # or as long as you want
q = Q( field__icontains=vals[0] )
for val in vals[1:]
    q = q | Q( field__icontains=val )

Model.objects.filter( q)
```

Comment: One could shorten this a bit using `functools.reduce`: `q = reduce(lambda x, y: x | Q(y), vals, Q())`

Comment: @dgw I prefer readable over shorter and cleverer. In some future maintenance year somebody to whom it's not obvious may have to work out what the heck that line does.

Comment: Agreed. But you do not need to initialize with the first element, you can initialize with a simple `Q()` and then iterate over the complete list. The resulting `Q` will be same.